# How to host ASP.NET MVC app on IIS10 win10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-10, iis-10

I dont know what did i do wrong but i keep getting this "**This site can’t be reached**"
I tryed allmost every solutions offerd here on stackoverflow and accross internet.

I instaled IIS and configured it just like they descirbed on

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

I published app to a folder with same name as Web site and Hostname i created in IIS.
I pointed IIS to look on that folder and when i try to browse i get that error.

I Set Application Pool to .NET CLR version v4.0.30319.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is an ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: Nope, but i tryed with ASP.NET MVC core and getting same results.

Comment: I think this is a binding problem. Go to your website, right click and select **Edit Bindings**. Make sure **All (Default is *)** for IP Address is selected.

Comment: I don't know did i got it correct, you want me to set ip address "All Unassigned"?

Comment: Yes, i thinks that's how it's called

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention above but web site is allready configured like that.

Comment: Is the binding port 80? Do you use some proxy or the error says something else?

Comment: Yes port is 80 but i added another (some random port 23456), No i don't use proxy.

Comment: Any other information or error? Can't quite see where's the problem.

Comment: "This site can’t be reached" and "DNS address could not be found." this is what i got after i try to reach web site.

Comment: What's the DNS address? Is it binded?

Comment: Where to look for dns server address?

Comment: Right click on your website and select Edit Bindings. There should be mapped with the default port 80 the name of the website: websitename.domain.com ...

Comment: Wohoo, i left hostname blank and it's working fine. THANKS alot for helping... I would loved to upvote you but no post and still under 15 rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your website and select **Edit Bindings**. There should be mapped with the default port 80 the name of the website: websitename.domain.com

Comment: I can't upvote becauze i don't have 15 reputation, but i promise i will when i get it.